# How to parse string in PHP?

Tags: php

I get string from server:

```
auto  status
        simple.cars  OK
        simple.moto  OK
        authorize.cars  OK
        authorize.moto  OK
```

I want to parse this by tabulation and get an array key (simple.cars) - value OK.

```
$math = preg_match_all("/^(.*)[\t\s]+(OK|FAIL)$/im", $result, $out);
        var_dump($out);
```

But it returns me empty array.

Comment: I do not get an empty array. See: [PHP Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/A0OJA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to build a map containing keys and their OK/FAIL values:

```php
$input = "auto  status\n         simple.cars  OK\n         simple.moto  OK\n         authorize.cars  OK\n 
    authorize.moto  OK";
preg_match_all("/(\S+)\s+(OK|FAIL)/", $input, $matches);
$map = array();
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($matches[1]); ++$i) {
    $map[$matches[1][$i]] = $matches[2][$i];
}
print_r($map);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [simple.cars] => OK
    [simple.moto] => OK
    [authorize.cars] => OK
    [authorize.moto] => OK
)
```

Comment: It works perfectly, what was wrong in my approach?

Comment: The pattern you used has problems.  I wouldn't use multiline mode here.